# Jquery mobile AJAX navigation not loading jquery elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile

Basically, I'm creating a radio station app (so far so good!) and i basically need the audio player at the bottom continuously playing whilst the user navigates through the app.
(This is written in Javascript by the way - using phonegap build) but obviously when the user goes to another page, the audio stops and they have to click play again.

I've thought of a way around this (AJAX navigation) and it works, its awesome and everything but this is the code im using to do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "a" ).on( "click", function( event ){
          event.preventDefault();

           $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
                var resp = $(data);

                $("#pageContent").html($("#pageContent", resp).html());


            }); 
        });
});
```

As you can see, it basically swaps the div called "pageContent" with the same div on the other pages but i have other jquery elements on the other pages (such as jquery themed lists, forms, buttons etc) and when i navigate this way ^ it doesnt style anything in jquery, it puts the forms out as basic html and im assuming its because it doesnt reload whats in the head?

I've tried many things, like

`$("head").html($("head", resp).html());`

That doesnt work :-(

So i wondered if anyone could help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post HTML markup?

Comment: just ask the question. why tell your whole life story?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- load a single shared CSS file that contains all the styles you would need among all the pages or
- load the styles inline

If you choose the second option you would need to read all the css files like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $( "a" ).on( "click", function( event ){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
                                var html = $.parseHTML(data);
                                $("#pageContent").html($('<div></div>').append(data).find('#pageContent').html());
                                var styles="";
                                $.each( html, function( i, el ) {
                                    if(el.nodeName=='LINK'){
                                        $.get($(el).attr('href'),function(data){
                                            $("#pageContent").append($("<style></style>").html(data));
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                        }); 
                });
        });
```

I Hope it helps.